# Dropdown menu over video?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap is there a way to overlay a glyphicon dropdown menu over a video (mp4) , or alternatively, can I make an mp4 a background?  I've tried everything and can't get it to work.  I can get the glyphicon to overlay the video, but can't make it function as a dropdown.  I can also get the dropdown to work over a background, but can't seem to make the video work as a background.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your dropdown menu div on video by using position absolute for dropdown div and use position relative for main content.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  Do you have a working example that you can show me?  I believe I tried this and the dropdown stopped working.

Comment: I think every thing work fine with this method. you can see url below. worked by me. :)

Comment: Hi, Usman, that is a nice site!  However, I don't see video, but static images.  I was wondering if there is way to have a dropdown on top of a video.